# Selenium browser.find_element_by_id.click downloaded file name

Tags: python, selenium

If I have a `python` script that clicks on a button on page that automatically downloads an excel sheet with a bunch of data, how do I get the download file name and location?

Code for webdriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver")
```

And after calling out the page, I do the following:

```
download_elem = browser.find_element_by_id("imgPrintToExcel")
download_elem.click()
```

That works perfectly and the excel file gets downloaded to my local "Downloads" folder with a default file name. Is there anyway to change the default name of the downloaded file or do I have to do that by going to the directory and changing the file name?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change download directory:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
directory = "C:/Downloads"
options.add_argument("download.default_directory=directory)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

If you want to change filename:

```
import re
import os
from pathlib import Path

directory = "C:/Downloads" # download directory
download_elem = browser.find_element_by_id("imgPrintToExcel")
path = link.get_attribute("href") # this will give us the link of file make sure it is the correct attribute for you
filename = re.findall(r'.*\/(.*?)$', path)[0] # we want just the filename so we will parse it
# in order to avoid mistaking our file we will check if there is a file with same name beforehand
if Path("%s/%s" % (directory, filename)).is_file(): # checking if filename exist
    name = ""
    type = ""
    if ('.' in filename): # checking if filename with type like .exe
        (name, type) = filename.split('.')
        type = "."+type
    else:
        name = filename
    filename = "%s(1)%s" % (name, type)
    i = 1
    while(True): # checking if there is other file duplicates
        if Path("%s/%s(%d)%s" % (directory, name, i, type)).is_file():
            i += 1
            filename = "%s(%d)%s" % (name, i, type)
        else:
            break;
else:
    pass
download_elem.click()
# wait for download to finish
os.rename(r"%s/%s" % (directory, filename),r"%s/new_filename" % directory')
```

Comment: Yeah that's why he needs to check attribute, I did include it in a comment in the code

Comment: and even you have a file name, secend file will have counter in name...

Comment: Ah, then he need to check if there is already a file in the directory with the same name?

Comment: so, for what check file neme in link, if he must find newer file?

Comment: What about the update, it first check if `filename` exist if it is existing then it will next check for seconds

Comment: Thank you guys  for your answers. I am working through it but one thing  that I am getting an error with the link.getattribute (link not defined)

Comment: @Jamaleas as I mentioned you need to check which attribute your download link is in, normally it is `src` or `href`, a little look in the source code and you'll find it

Comment: @MobrineHayde, sorry about that. It is a "src" but when I click on the image to download the file, the file name is different than the src.

Comment: That's completely not included in the question, but do you mind giving giving me how it is like, I might help you

Answer (score 0):

set download folder for browser and wait for new file...
Code (java) for webdriver:

```
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<>();
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", DOWNLOADDIR);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```